# (Rails) Test fails during late night time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, time, relationship

My rails application is covered by many tests. All the tests pass in regular situations. That is, excluding when it's late at night.

There's actually a few tests that end up failing when it's night. All these tests involve modifying a model's time attribute and seeing if related models are affected.

```
test "changing time should affect hours" do
    // ..User is loaded.
    user.attend(event)
    assert_equal 1, user.hours // User attends a 1 hour event that has passed. 
    // Move event to the future.
    event.update_attributes(date: Date.today,
                              start_time: Time.now,
                              end_time: Time.now + 1.hour)
    assert_equal 0, attendance_of(user).hours // Passes in day, fails during night
  end

test "valid event creation" do
    // Count does NOT change by 1 at night.
    assert_difference '@group.events.count', 1 do
      post group_events_path(@group), event: { ...
                                                date: Date.today,
                                                start_time: Time.now,
                                                end_time: Time.now + 1.hour,
                                                ... }
    end
  end
```

What is going on here? For reference, here's what I currently use to determine when to update an *attendance* (which is something that an *event* has). This comes from the event controller:

```
  def not_ended?
    date.future? || (date.today? &&
      (Time.now.seconds_since_midnight < end_time.seconds_since_midnight))
  end

  def update_attendances
    // ... Determine the new date, start, and end time values through ActiveRecord::Dirty
    if not_ended?
      remove_checks = true
    end
    attendances.each do |attendance|
      new_checked = remove_checks ? false : attendance.checked
      attendance.update_attributes(went: new_start, left: new_end,
                                    checked: new_checked)
    end
  end
end
```

Validating an event to make sure its times aren't weird:

```
    def valid_time
      if start_time == end_time
        // Error...
      end
      if start_time > end_time
        // Error...
      end
    end
```

Time zone in **application.rb**:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: One word: timezones. I don't see the error yet, but it must be them.

Comment: Where do you run those tests? Locally or some CI service (semaphore, travis)?

Comment: Yep! timezones :-) We also have some similar tests!

Comment: Also, what exactly is that "late night time" in UTC?

Comment: not necessarily time-zones. To me this looks like a boundary error when the event goes into the next day the system thinks it's actually in the past.

Comment: I run the tests locally. Timezones? I have my timezone set to be in Pacific Time, not sure where a difference would come into play. I run my tests locally. Let me clarify on "late night": I'm talking about the last hour of the day.

Toby, you may be closest to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `not_ended?` method is broken. It doesn't work when the event starts before midnight, but ends after. In that case the date is today (assuming the data is based on start time) but the number of seconds since midnight of the end of the event is less that the current time.

In these situations you shouldn't be trying to deal with dates and times separately. You should have a way to retrieve the datetime of the end of the event and compare that with the current datetime.

Comment: This may just be it. However, I need a good method for getting the datetime for the event. The event's **date** is a `date` while it's **start_time** and **end_time** attributes are `time`s. Trying to figure this out.

Comment: It turns out that my models aren't set up for multi-day events.

Answer (score 2):

Use Time.zone.now or timecop.freeze to freeze the timezone as your  test is probably using system time and not rails app config time